# ZK Replace Image Content

Tags: java, image, zk

I have an image on a zul page, that I need to replace using the controller.

I've tried using Image.setContent(bufferedImage) as well as Image.setSrc(base64EncodedString) neither of these update the displayed image.

I've also attempted calling Image.invalidate() after setting the source and content, this does not update the image either.

My image tag on the .zul looks like this

```
<image id="imgStreaming" width="200" height="200" style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid #b9b9b9; border-radius:0px; color:#ccc; min-width:200px; min-height:200px;" />
```

The code in the controller looks like this

```
JsonArray ja = json.getAsJsonObject().get("A").getAsJsonArray();                    
BufferedImage bufferImg = decodeToImage(ja.get(0).toString());                    
imgStreaming.setContent(bufferImg);
imgStreamingFingerprint.invalidate();
```

the decodeToImage method simply takes the base64 string and converts it back to a BufferedImage

Comment: Reading through [the documentation of `Image`](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Image), I saw that `setSrc` expects the URI path to the image, not the encoded image content. For your purpose of what the documentation calls "generated dynamically", `setContent` should be the right approach, and it should support `BufferedImage`, too. Could you try the examples shown on the documentation page and see if those work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK image content  contains AImage object. So you need to create this object before you can change content of your image element. 
See example below

```
<image content="@bind(vm.currentImage)"/>

URL url = new URL(IMAGE_URL);
currentImage = new AImage(url);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander, even though I went a different route with this particular piece of code, your code would have worked perfectly as well. I had decided to rather manage the streaming of images to the particular component using javascript and post the result once processed to the server using the zAu interface.